# datatables + hiding all columns button

Tags: datatables

in [datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnGroups.html) I want to be able to hide all columns, but can't seem to get the syntax right.

This from the code below and the above link, creates a button that shows all the columns. Is there a way to write this so that I can hide all columns?

```
        {
            extend: 'colvisGroup',
            text: 'Show all',
            show: ':hidden'
        }
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Office info',
                show: [ 1, 2 ],
                hide: [ 3, 4, 5 ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'HR info',
                show: [ 3, 4, 5 ],
                hide: [ 1, 2 ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Show all',
                show: ':hidden'
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

i have tried something like the below with other permutations, but no joy, can anyone advise, and/or how I might find it in the documentation.

```
{
    extend: 'colvisGroup',
    text: 'Show None',
    visibility: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    extend: 'colvisGroup',
    text: 'Show None',
    hide: [':gt(1)'],
    //show: [0, 1, 2],
    //hide: [0, 1, 2],
    //hide: ['*']
}
```

this worked for me, only 2 column visible...

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, although I am not sure why the `0` does not show the first column. it also works to leave it blank  `show: [],`

```
{
extend: 'colvisGroup',
text: 'Show None',
show: [0],
hide: ['*']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine the number of columns bind in datatable and then set all columns visibility false at once.

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
var columnCounts = oTable.columns().nodes().length;
for ( var i=0; i<columnCounts; i++ ) {
   oTable.fnSetColumnVis(i, false, false);
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me - although I had to change the line inside the loop to: `oTable.column(i).visible(false, false)` because it didn't let me use `fnSetColumnVis` function